# Run Tensorflow 2.0 code on Tensorflow 1.x

Tags: tensorflow, upgrade

I have a code that was running on colab with Tensorflow 2.0 and now I am trying to run it on a GPU with Tensorflow 1.14 and facing several errors. Is there an easy way to upgrade to tensorflow 2.0 or is it better to modify the code and make it working on the current version?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working on colab with TF 2.0, then you can uninstall `TF-GPU 1.14` and install latest version of `TF 2.4`.

```
# Uninstall tensorflow 
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu == 1.14

# Requires the latest pip
pip install --upgrade pip

# Current stable release for CPU and GPU
pip install tensorflow (which install latest version of TF 2.4)
```

To know more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)